# Remove Gmail account from Gmail app without removing Google account from the phone

Tags: gmail, google-account

I don't use Gmail for my e-mail. However, I want to use the Gmail app for my work e-mail. So, how do I keep only my work e-mail in the Gmail app, removing the Gmail account from it completely?

I still want to have Play Store and Google Fi to be associated with my account. To my understanding, when I try to remove my Gmail account from the Gmail app, it suggests completely removing my Google account from the phone.

I'm on Android 9.

Comment: Using a Google app without using the Google service it belongs to is not an intended use case by Google.

Comment: If you do Clear data on Gmail app from Settings app, and restart the Gmail app it asks you to select account. Ignore the Google account and add your non-Google account there. Might work.

Comment: I think you can add it as a secondary email, why is it specifically important to remove the other email ?

Answer (score 1):

For me, I have a slightly different need but the same solution applies. For me, I use the unified inbox in Gmail for work (I have multiple work email accounts) but I also need to sometimes check my son's school email.

A solution that works for me is to use Secure Folder (for Samsung) or dual apps (for Xiaomi or other phone makers). This creates two separate profiles with separate Google accounts.

The one asking the question here could then put their personal account and Google Play in one profile and their work emails in the other profile

Answer (score 1):

Emails and Play Store accounts are not related. There are 2 ways

1. You can remove the account from Android's `Settings` -> `Account management` despite its warnings, and then just log back into Play Store with it.
2. Open the Gmail app, press the hamburger menu, go to `Settings`, select the email address, and disable sync.

For the record, I have multiple Gmail accounts and change which one I  am using in the Play Store multiple times a day. And I don't use Gmail for emails at all. Underneath, one has nothing to do with the other.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this has always been the case?  I might not be remembering correctly, but I thought this wasn't possible years ago.

Comment: Very helpful answer.  Thanks.  I made an edit based on what I believe you are trying to convey.  Can you please proofread my edit to ensure my edit is correct?